# Linux find and -mtime usage

Tags: linux, find, mtime

I have two different linux based systems where the find command doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I have a directory. In it I run...

```
ls -l
```

and the system returns...

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 panopticon36 panopticon36 4096 May 22 12:28 folder1
drwxr-xr-x 2 panopticon36 panopticon36 4096 May 22 12:28 folder2
drwxr-xr-x 2 panopticon36 panopticon36 4096 May 22 12:25 folder3
drwxr-xr-x 2 panopticon36 panopticon36 4096 May 24 09:52 folder4
```

today is 5/24/17.

In the same directory, if I run...

```
find . -mtime +1 -type d
```

the system returns nothing.

From my understanding, the find command should find all directories "-type d" in the current directory "." that are more than 1 day old "-mtime +1".
So...

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

should all be listed to my understanding. Two systems under my care are exhibiting this behavior. Am I doing something incorrectly or missing something? Could something be modifying directories in such a way that ls -l does not reflect the correct date modified? Is there something else I could attempt to troubleshoot the issue? All help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the weird way the `mtime` is rounded up, `+1` means "48 hours or more". This is documented on the man page.

The way to memorize it is to start from the most basic use: `-mtime 1` which means that file was accessed 24 hours ago plus any fraction (for example 24+23 hours would also match). From this follows "logically" what `+1` and `-1` mean.

Comment: Yeah but folders 1 through 3 were all modified (May 22 according to ls -l) 2 days ago, so +1 should list them. I see what you are saying and that would make sense if the folders were last modified May 23rd.

Comment: Only if you have run `find` on May 24, 12:28 or later. Have you? And it could be a timezone-related issue like [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/207792/find-mtime-does-not-work-as-expected-on-files-with-different-timezones?rq=1).

Comment: I'm sorry. You are correct. +1 indicates files a full 48 hours later than the time at which the command is run. Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate it.

Comment: @DeanTaylor You may want to look at `-daystart` if you'd rather count calendar days than seconds